# HTTP Request POST.Upload JRXML file via JaspeReports Server

Tags: post, jasperserver

I want upload/update report template JRXML file on JasperReports Server.

The official documentation doesn't contain a minimal example for updating report template
What is raw request which uploads/updates report template xml via JasperReports Server REST API?

I tried to run JasperServer java tests(using maven): http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/jasperserver/
But I couldn't. There were many errors.

Then I found this sample test for updating image in Jasper Server resources: 
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-rest-web-service-api
It works!

I wrote my request for update JRXML file

here is my raw request
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b2dd458868243b37c795

here is response
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/916f09199103665b97c0

What am I doing wrong in my request?

Comment: Sorry for me mistakes in the text. I'm from Russia

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.The resource descriptor in request must be reportunit, but not а resource descriptor of jrxml file!!!