# How to deploy a report (jrxml file) through the Jasper PHP/REST API?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

How to deploy a report (`jrxml` file) through the Jasper PHP/REST API
to the Jasper Reports Server?

Comment: May be this post can help you: [HTTP Request POST.Upload JRXML file via JaspeReports Server](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15832107/876298)

Comment: You can also look at this post: [REST Web Service API: upload/update report template](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12596435/876298)

Comment: The [*JasperReports Server Web Services Guide*](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/docs/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide.pdf) contains information related to your issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For deploying Jasper reports on Jasper Server using Rest-API you can use following method:

### Uploading JRXML file

```
JRXML_DATA=$(cat $PATHTOJRXMLFILE/$JRXML_FILE)

curl  -X POST $JASPER_REST_HOST/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/reports \
-H "Content-Type:application/jrxml" \
-H "Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=test" \
-H "Content-Description:test file" \
-d "$JRXML_DATA" \
--user $JASPER_USERNAME:$JASPER_USERNAME
```

### Creating ReportUnit

```
RESOURCEDESCRIPTOR_JSON=$(cat $REPORT/deployable/reportunit.json)

curl  -X POST $JASPER_REST_HOST/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/reports \
-H "Content-Type:application/repository.reportUnit+json" \
-d "$RESOURCEDESCRIPTOR_JSON" \
--user $JASPER_USERNAME:$JASPER_PASSWORD
```

### ResourceDescriptor for reportUnit example

```
{
    "uri": "/reports/test_report", 
    "label": "test_report", 
    "description": "description", 
    "permissionMask": "0",
    "version": "0" ,
    "alwaysPromptControls": "true",
    "controlsLayout": "popupScreen",
    "jrxml": {
        "jrxmlFileReference": {
            "uri": "/reports/test"
        }
    }
}
```

### Resource Descriptor references

http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/v2-resource-descriptor-types

Comment: I do not see how it uses RestAPI or php code to deploy jasper report xml. Also it is using a curl call and linux specific syntax. Not a programming solution.

Comment: Actually It doesn't uses PHP code but uses RestAPI of jasper server. I thnk the ultimate moto is to consume RestAPI whatever technology you use. Curl call is consuming RestAPI only. Why you feel what curl is hitting is not RestAPI.

Answer (score 1):

To upload a jrxml file, create a `ResourceDescriptor` with `PROP_HAS_DATA` = `true` and insert the jrxml content in a multipart `PUT` request.

After a while of researching and investigating I got it running and developed a PHP class that's easy to use.

http://blog.flowl.info/2013/jasper-php-library-on-github/

To upload a jrxml file this code does the job:

```
// Init the Jasper connection
require_once('Jasper/Jasper.php');
$jasper = new \Jasper\Jasper();
$jasper->login('jasperadmin', 'jasperadmin', 'jasper.host.com:8080');

// Create a Resource Descriptor object for the jrxml file
$jrxml = new \Jasper\JasperJrxml('/reports/test.jrxml');

// Upload the Resource Descriptor object with content
$jasper->createContent($jrxml, file_get_contents('templates/test.jrxml'));
```

To create a report unit, go on with the following lines:

```
// Datasource Resource Descriptor
$mongo = new \Jasper\JasperDatasource();
$mongo->setPropIsReference('true');
$mongo->setPropReferenceUri('/datasources/mongo_local_test');

// Put everything together and deploy the report
$report->addChildResource($mongo);
$report->addChildResource($jrxml);

// Want to see the Resource Descriptor of the Report Unit?
// true = pretty print
print_r($report->getXml(true));

// Create a the Report Unit
$jasper->createResource($report);
```