# JasperServer RESTv2 API create report with subreports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I was following stackOverflow answer:

[How to deploy a report (jrxml file) through the Jasper PHP/REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347906/how-to-deploy-a-report-jrxml-file-through-the-jasper-php-rest-api)

I deployed subreport, report and POST with reportUnit xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<reportUnit>  
    <uri>/reports/public/testMaster</uri>
    <alwaysPromptControls>true</alwaysPromptControls>
    <controlsLayout>popupScreen</controlsLayout>
    <label>testMaster</label>
    <description>Test description</description>
    <permissionMask>0</permissionMask>
    <version>0</version>
    <jrxmlFileReference>
        <uri>/reports/testMaster</uri>
        </jrxmlFileReference>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <name>testSubreport</name>
            <fileReference>
                <uri>/reports/testSubreport</uri>
            </fileReference>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</reportUnit>
```

on http://jasper:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/reports/public

It was all fine but the type of subreport included was "Resource" not "JRXML".

When I tried to POST reportUnit for subreport it gave me 400:

```
[{"message":"Invalid JRXML",
  "errorCode":"illegal.parameter.value.error",
  "parameters":["JRXML.content","JRXML.content"]}]
```

So obviously I'm missing something.

When I deploy this subreport manually (with GUI) it works just fine.

Can anyone give me any idea how to create raport unit with subreports included, using rest_v2 api?

Comment: Are you sure that the subreport is also deployed?

Comment: yes, it is deployed (using POST) as "File" (and occurs in web GUI) but its included in reportUnit as "Resource", while when deploying manually its "JRXML"

Comment: Did you use the specifications from the first answer of the question you referred to? How does your code look like?

Comment: It should not matter if you see the subreport as "Resource". You should still be able to run the report. Did you run it?