# How to deploy *.jrxml reports to Jasper Server using scripting

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I would like to be able to  deploy reports to jasperserver using some kind of scripts, not via the Jaspersoft Studio GUI

I tried 
`js-export --uris /reports --output-dir myExportedReports`
hoping to re-import the same.

However, while exploring the `myExportedReports` folder, there were only `*.xml` and associated `*.data` files without the original `*.jrxml`.

Did anyone  deploy new reports (report folders) to Jasper Server without using Jaspersoft Studio?

Comment: One of the `.data` file may contain the actual JRXML which you can edit.

Comment: You can also take a look at the JasperServer REST web services, that's what Jaspersoft Studio is using to deploy reports.  With some effort you should be able to write a script that makes the REST calls needed to deploy a report.

Comment: Yes it looks like a pretty good approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347906/how-to-deploy-a-report-jrxml-file-through-the-jasper-php-rest-api
I've found  some `curl`  samples here and will look further into the REST API

Answer (score 2):

So I checked out the Jasper Server REST interface.
It looks like a two steps process

1. Upload the JRXML file

```
JRXML_DATA=`cat "report.jrxml"`
curl  -X POST http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/reports/ \
-H "Content-Type:application/jrxml" \
-H "Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=My-report" \
-H "Content-Description:My-report-description" \
-d "$JRXML_DATA" \
--user jasperadmin:jasperadmin
```

2. Create the Report Unit and assign a data source

```
curl  -X POST http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources/reports \
-H "Content-Type:application/repository.reportUnit+json" \
-d '{"uri": "/reports/my_report","label": "my-report","description": "My-report description",  "permissionMask": "0", "version": "0" , "alwaysPromptControls": "true","controlsLayout": "popupScreen", "jrxml": {"jrxmlFileReference": { "uri": "/reports/my-report"} },"dataSource": {"dataSourceReference": { "uri": "/datasources/Reporting_DB"}}}' \
--user  jasperadmin:jasperadmin
```

Comment: in my case, uploading with a REST interface, my jrxml files gets type file instead of type report ?
https://i.postimg.cc/P5nrDLcV/image.png